# Standalone Openid Authorization server with NodeJs

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid, node-oidc-provider

I'm looking for some kind of standalone Identity Provider (Authz Server) that use the library...

https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider

I'm confused with some configs and I'd like to be able to guide myself in the OpenID workflow to provide the right configurations.

I need to provide custom claims and login hint support.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say standalone, what do you mean ?

As I know, the lib Node-Oidc-provider allow you to use the implementation alongside Express Js, Koa or even standalone as the lib itself is built around koa js, you can use it.

I recommend you to read: https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/tree/main/docs#mounting-oidc-provider

Or checkout example folder: https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/example

Do I misunderstand you ? Please update your question with more details please

Comment: I think those references are clear, this library is confusing at the beginning.

Comment: The library is extremely confusing and doesn't come with a complete end-to-end simple example.  I have yet to get it working in the most simplistic way.